# remove the lines from RichtextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, richtextbox

I have a richTextBox and has more than 50 lines... I like to remove the lines has MOVE STORAGE .. For example below first line of words ***(in the richtextbox has actually two lines)***  with ending semi column has MOVE STORAGE word, than remove all 2 lines.

```
ALTER TABLE "CAMPUS_SITE" MOVE STORAGE ( INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT);

DROP INDEX XIE2TBL_A;
DROP INDEX XPKTBL_A;
```

Expected result:

```
DROP INDEX XIE2TBL_A;
DROP INDEX XPKTBL_A;
```

Comment: You want it to be regex?

Comment: Actually you have 4 lines, empty line also there you want to remove that too or?

Answer (score 2):

From your question,it seems that you want to remove the line that contains "MOVE STORAGE".You should try this;

```
var text = "";//Holds the text of current line being looped.
        var startindex = 0;//The position where selection starts.
        var endindex = 0;//The length of selection.

        for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)//Loops through each line of text in RichTextBox
        {
            text = richTextBox1.Lines[i];//Stores current line of text.
            if (text.Contains("MOVE STORAGE") == true)//Checks if the line contains MOVE STORAGE.
            {
                startindex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);//If match is found the index of first char of that line is stored in startindex.
                endindex = text.Length;//Gets the length of line till semicolon and stores it in endindex.
                richTextBox1.Select(startindex, endindex);//Selects the text.
                richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(richTextBox1.SelectedText, string.Empty);//Replaces the text with empty string.
            }
        }
```